# Do I need to pass all url params to react query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Let's say I would like to get all params from url and combine it with react query api request. I have `name` and `age` param in url - to get access to it I can use react-router-dom.

```js
const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
```

Do I need to pass all url params to first argument of react query? (like this)
Bacause if we will have like 10 params, we will need to pass all searchParams.get(property) to react query? There is no way to pass one single 'variable' from useSearchParams to react query to track all params whenever they change?

```js
const { isLoading, error, data, isFetching } = useQuery(["users", searchParams.get('name'), searchParams.get('age)], () =>
  API.getUsers({
    name: searchParams.get('name') || filters.name || "",
    age: searchParams.get('age') || filters.age || "",
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any json serializable string to the query key (and even non-serializable things when you provide your own `queryKeyHashFn`).

It is important to include all dependencies that you are actually using in the queryFn to get automatic refetches whenever any of those change, so in your case, I would do:

```
const userParams = {
  name: searchParams.get('name') || filters.name || "",
  age: searchParams.get('age') || filters.age || "",
}

const { isLoading, error, data, isFetching } = useQuery(
  ["users", userParams],
  () => API.getUsers(userParams)
);
```

that isn't really more code because you have to build `userParams` anyways to pass it to `API.getUsers`